# The method setPositiveButton

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

*Hello everyone, I just started with android and I am on my first project.
I am not a developer base, so please excuse me if my language is not fit. That one week already that I'm stuck on this alert dialog function. I ask you to help me. Thank you!*

```
public class Myclass extends Activity implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{

    private TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lyt);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(tv.getContext())
    .setMessage("Blah blah blah.\n Fine pring.\n Do you accept all our terms and conditions?")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setTitle("Terms of Service")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", this)
    .setNegativeButton("No", this)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .create();
    ad.show();
        }
});
    }

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(which){
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE: // yes
            Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + tv.getText().toString()));
            startActivity(call);
        break;
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE: // no
        tv.setText("Oh lalala");
        break;
        default:
        // nothing
        break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is not working? What is your question?

Comment: replace setNegativeButton("No", this) with setNegativeButton("No", YourActivity.this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
.setPositiveButton("Yes", this)
.setNegativeButton("No", this)
```

with

```
.setPositiveButton("Yes", Myclass.this)
.setNegativeButton("No", Myclass.this)
```

Because, that statement is inside `onClick` of anonymous class of type `TextView.OnClickListener`. So, you will get compile error, as you are trying to pass `View.OnCLickListener` instead of `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`

By the way, you should at least have mentioned that you are getting compile error.

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass this which is ref of tv.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener()  to Dialog interface use this 
try this .this will work for sure.

.

```
setPositiveButton("Yes", Myclass.this)
.setNegativeButton("No", Myclass.this)
```